# SwiftUI TextField - Binding values with custom delegate

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uitextfielddelegate

I wanted to preform live formatting to a value entered into a SwiftUI TextField, so I used introspect to add a custom delegate, like in UIKit. This caused the .onChange to stop working. If I comment out the delegate, the .onChange block works. How do I get the binding to work with the custom delegate?

TextFieldView:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI


struct TextFieldView: View {
    
    @State private var inputString: String = ""
    
    var customDelegate = CustomTextFieldDelegate()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("", text: $inputString)
                .addTextFieldDelegate(delegate: customDelegate)
        }
        .onChange(of: inputString) { _ in
            print("inputString: \(inputString)")
        }
    }
}
```

Introspect:

```
extension View {
    func addTextFieldDelegate(delegate: UITextFieldDelegate) -> some View {
        introspect(.textField, on: .iOS(.v15...)) { textfield in
            textfield.delegate = delegate
        }
    }
}
```

Custom Delegate:

```
class CustomTextFieldDelegate: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    override init() { }
    
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
            return true
    }
    
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        
        guard let text = textField.text, let textRange = Range(range, in: text) else {
            return false
        }
        
        var updatedText = text.replacingCharacters(in: textRange, with: string)
        updatedText.removeAll(where: {$0 == ":"})
        
        let finalLength = updatedText.count + updatedText.count/2 - 1
        
        if finalLength > 8 {
            return false
        }
        for i in stride(from: 2, to: finalLength, by: 3) {
            let index = updatedText.index(updatedText.startIndex, offsetBy: i)
            updatedText.insert(":", at: index)
        }
        textField.text = updatedText
        
        return false
    }
    

}
```

**Edit 01:**

What I want to achieve is to add a ":" ever two characters as the input is being typed into the TextField. I would prefer not to use introspect, but not sure how to modify the variable inputString without triggering the onChange handler again, thus leading to an infinite loop.

Comment: As you have seen, going "under the covers" to access the UIKit view behind the SwiftUI view is a bad idea.  Even if it worked now it is likely to be fragile - Apple could change the implementation of the `TextField` in the future.  You should implement all of your logic in the `onChange` handler.

Comment: @Paulw11, Thanks for your feedback. I'd prefer not to use introspect, but can't figure out how to format the inputString inside the onChange handler without triggering it again, thus leading to an infinite loop. Edited the question to clarify what I was originally trying to achieve

Comment: RRR, what I've done to fix infinite loops is to have the onChange code check to see if the new value is actually different before installing it into the bound variable. If there's no change, don't do an assignment. The means your onChange handler gets called twice, but only twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not rely on the fact that SwiftUI is built on UIKit - This could well change in the future.

You don't need to use the `UITextFieldDelegate` - You can perform your processing in the `onChange` handler.

We can check that the old and new values are the same to prevent an `onChange` loop.

For example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var oldValue = ""
    @State var inputString = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("XX:XX:XX:XX", text:$inputString)
        }
        .onChange(of: inputString) { newValue in
            self.formatTextField(newValue)
        }
    }
    
    func formatTextField(_ newValue: String) {
        guard self.oldValue != self.code else {
            return
        }
        var finalValue = newValue
        if newValue.count > self.oldValue.count {
            finalValue = self.processInsert(newValue: newValue, oldValue: self.oldValue)
        } else {
            finalValue = self.processDelete( newValue: newValue, oldValue: self.oldValue)
        }
        self.oldValue = finalValue
        self.inputString = finalValue
    }
    
    func processInsert(newValue: String, oldValue:String) -> String {
        guard newValue.count < 12 else {
            return oldValue
        }
        var characters = newValue
        characters.removeAll { $0 == ":"}
        var finalValue = ""
        
        for i in 0..<characters.count {
            finalValue.append(characters[characters.index(characters.startIndex,offsetBy: i)])
            if i < 7 && i > 0 && (i-1) % 2 == 0 {
                finalValue.append(":")
            }
        }
        
        return finalValue
        
    }
    
    func processDelete(newValue: String, oldValue: String) -> String {
        var finalValue = newValue
        var input = finalValue
        input.removeAll { $0 == ":"}
        let length = input.count
        if length > 0 && length % 2 == 0 {
            finalValue = String(finalValue.prefix(finalValue.count-1))
        }
        return finalValue
    }
}
```

Comment: The code changes the same state variable `inputString ` in the closure of `onChange(of: inputString)`. You may get a warning `onChange(of: String) action tried to update multiple times per frame.` Actually, it has a flaky behaviour, too. So, unfortunately, this solution doesn't seem to be suitable. A better way is probably to move the logic into an ObservableObject.

Comment: It worked for me and I did not get any warnings.

Comment: I think, it may work without flakiness, which depends on the function and condition to set the underlying value. So IMHO, it's not a universally solution. I stumbled over this just a few hours ago, where I tried to implement a logic which prevents mutating a string except adding a new character at the end. It was incredible difficult to accomplish this in the View. Using Binding was even more weird: in iOS 17 TextField just ignores the change from a Binding called from withthe setter, while it works "somehow" in iOS 16.